# POWER BI > Trying to calculate the daily spend between two dates

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Stuck on what I thought would be a fairly simply issue. Really hoping someone can help me out with this. Thanks in advance.

I have a table containing a list of work orders. Each row has an unique ID, a work order start date, a work order end date, and a daily bill rate. With these data values, I need to calculate the spend amount across the past and the future based on the different start and end dates for each work order.

Below is an example of the Workorder table (dates are in DD/MM/YYYY format):

| WorkOrderID | Workorder Start Date | Workorder End Date | Bill Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WO000004 | 1/02/2016 | 30/12/2017 | 85.75 |
| WO000001 | 2/01/2018 | 30/06/2018 | 50.25 |
| WO000005 | 14/05/2020 | 6/07/2022 | 125.95 |
| WO000007 | 22/02/2022 | 3/11/2025 | 160.55 |
| WO000006 | 18/03/2022 | 25/08/2024 | 145.25 |
| WO000002 | 15/09/2022 | 30/05/2025 | 90.85 |
| WO000008 | 1/01/2023 | 30/04/2024 | 87.9 |
| WO000003 | 25/04/2023 | 18/10/2024 | 140.5 |

How might I write a solution in Power BI DAX get the following expected result:

| Date | WorkOrderID | Projected Spend |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/01/2015 | blank | 0 |
| 2/01/2015 | blank | 0 |
| 3/01/2015 | blank | 0 |
| … |  |  |
| 1/02/2016 | WO000004 | 85.75 |
| … |  |  |
| 1/03/2022 | WO000005 | 125.95 |
| 1/03/2022 | WO000007 | 160.55 |
| … |  |  |
| 19/03/2022 | WO000005 | 125.95 |
| 19/03/2022 | WO000007 | 160.55 |
| 19/03/2022 | WO000006 | 145.25 |
| … |  |  |
| 30/09/2024 | WO000002 | 90.85 |
| 30/09/2024 | WO000003 | 140.5 |

So, the solution I'm after will cycle through each date between two given dates and if that date falls between the Work Order Start/End Date, it then lists the WorkOrder ID and the Bill Rate.

I've tried CALCULATETABLE, SUMMARIZE, SUMMARIZECOLUMNS and various DAX functions to get a generated table but and hitting issues when comparing the Date column to the Work Order Start and End Date.

Again, thank you for any and all help you can provide.

Kind regards.